# How to make a nice vector field with inkscape

Tags: inkscape

I would like to create a "vector field" that emerges from nothing. That is I would like the size of the vectors to be large in some small region, and getting smaller to nothing near the boundary of that region.

I have managed to imitate the effect vaguely by just drawing lots of arrows like so
[image]

but this takes ages and the end result is not nice anyway. I was thinking there may be a way to make this effect by creating a grid of arrows and then distorting it in an Escher-esque, hyperbolic manner 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_Limit_III#/media/File:Hyperbolic_domains_642.png 
but I haven't found a way to do this anywhere.

Would be very grateful for any help!

Many Thanks,
Adam.

Answer (score 1):

Within inkscape, the most likely process would be:

- draw object
- clone/duplicate/cut-and-paste/arrange into whatever patter you want
- group them all (or union)
- use the envelope distort feature to accomplish the 'field' effect.

Here's a video that explains that particular feature: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l3BHcregNUs

Comment: Thanks DA01, I have tried that idea and it is helpful to create a nice wavy field but it doesn't work to get the field dying off with smaller arrows at the boundary. Any ideas how to create that effect?